Short story where automated freight ships regularly come to a mining planet to collect the ore
Was rummaging the pages of an SF anthology many years back and have thought about one of its stories but can't remember what it was called or who wrote it. Help! The title is probably the name of a fictional ore but I'm not sure. I remember this: automated freight ships regularly come to a mining planet to take the ore. The tone was pretty dark. I would guess it was published early this century. I was probably not told from the point of view of a character but more of an omniscient style narrator.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be a bit more specific about approximately what year you read this?  Do you recall any of the other stories in the anthology?

I recall this one. The people on the planet had basically been abandoned to a life of slavery and servitude.

"Many years back" .    "Published early this century".          You're causing some pain!

Unlikely, but automated freight ships do go to collect ore from a planet in "Masters of Space" (1961) by E.E. "doc" Smith and E. Everett Evans. However, the planet is inhabited by robots, who were left there thousands of years ago (until the humans arrive). This is not a good book, though it has some interesting ideas (I suspect Smith wrote the good bits and Evans wrote the rest).

Could be "Pipeline to Pluto" by Murray Leinster, which is a story about automated mining ships that is pretty dark, so it matches the main points you stated. And I too read it in an anthology--Groff Conklin's SCIENCE FICTION TERROR TALES.
Here is a pretty detailed summary of the story which should resolve whether it's the one you remember.
https://sffremembrance.com/2023/10/17/short-story-review-pipeline-to-pluto-by-murray-leinster/
